# when I try to insert the data I got unhandledRejection: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add multiple data in mysql database but I am getting SQL syntax error;

I have followed this article https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp

```
  const sql =
    "INSERT INTO test `ID`, `Name`, `Address`, `Phone`, `HomeAddress` values ?";
  const values = [
    [1, "fathe", "Dhaka", 1017310, "Madhabdi"],
    [1, "fathe", "Dhaka", 1017310, "Madhabdi"]
];
  dbconnection.query(sql, [
    [values],
    function (err: any, results: any) {
      console.log(results, err);
    },
  ]);
});
```

**error - unhandledRejection: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ID, Name, Address, Phone, HomeAddress values ((1, 'fathe', 'Dhaka', 1017310, ...' at line 1**

Answer (score 0):

The parameters required for `.query()` should be `.query(sql string, [parameters], error object)`. But it seems you are passing an array within array on the 2nd parameter.

```
 dbconnection.query(sql, [values],
    function (err: any, results: any) {
      console.log(results, err);
    }
 );
```